# How can I decode utf-8 in php

Tags: php, utf-8, decode, encode, codeigniter-4

I used this and others in my Codeigniter website,

```
⇾
```

I encode and decode using HTML entities.

I declared this:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

in my header but I kept getting this

```
â‡¾
```

any solution?

Comment: how about `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`?

Comment: It didn't work, have tried it before now